# How to persist an entity with compound partly generated key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

I have an entity, e.g A which contains 3 fields as compound key, where id is sequence-generated:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(APK.class)
public class A extends AbstractEntity {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "_A_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "A_SEQ", sequenceName= "A_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
private Integer a1;

@Id
private Integer a2;

@Id
private String a3;

....

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "a1", referencedColumnName = "b1", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "a2", referencedColumnName = "b2", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private B b;
```

So, As a1,a1,a3 are parts of compound key, i can have e.g. :
1222, 1, "s",
1222, 1, "m" - primaries, coz they R uniq. But! I cannot implement such a case coz when im persisting a new entity - a1 is generated (but i dont need it this time). How to avoid this?

And then how to better commet A and B, if A has 3 parts primary a1,a2,a3 (many) and B just to fields (b1 to a1 and b2 to a2) (one), eg:
in A (a1, a2, a3):

1. 1222,1,"S",
2. 1222,1,"M",
3. 1222,1,"K"

in B (b1, b2):
1222,1

Thank You!

Comment: Don't use JPA sequencing.  Sequencing is used to make a1 unique, which you apparently do not want, since you want to reuse a1 values in different combinations of a2 and a3.  So remove it, and assign your own values to a1.  That, or use JPA sequencing and don't bother using a composite pK.  There is no need to have the two other fields if you have a unique a1 field to use as the pk - it makes everything much more simple and efficient.

Comment: Yeah) My the only concern there is that db use this sequence....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your data model, and you are building a different Object model on top of it.  If you have an existing DB and it is using the sequence, I don't see how you can change your object model to start using a composite PK and composite foreign keys.  You usually have to use what is there already.  And if the DB is using a1 as a unique key, I don't see why the app would start using a1,a2,a3 as one unique key when a1 will do.